# quotient space and direct sum

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $Z=X\oplus Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are two Banach spaces. Under what conditions, we may say that $Y$ is isomorphic to $Z/X$?

Comment: No additional conditions. It is easy to check that $(X\oplus Y )/X$ is isomorphic to $Y$ and $(X \oplus Y )/Y$ is isomorphic to $X$. However, if $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$, then $X$ may not be isomorphic to $Y \oplus (X/Y )$, see [Banach space theory](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-7515-7.pdf) p. 18 and Exercise 12.50 on p. 573.

Comment: @GeorgeBrown THX!

Comment: Not at all. The paragraphs on p. 17 may be useful to you, too. "The spaces $X$ and $Y$ are algebraically isomorphic to the subspaces $\{(x, 0) : x \in  X\}$ and $\{(0, y) : y \in Y \}$ of $X\oplus Y$, respectively." "The spaces $X$ and $Y$ are isometric to the subspaces $\{(x, 0) : x \in X\}$ and $\{(0, y) :
y \in Y \}$ of $X \oplus Y$, respectively."